# grouby() function in Pandas returning IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2

Tags: python, pandas, version

After upgrading Python environment I have noticed that function `groupby()` from pandas library returns error message of type

```
IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 2
```

occasionally, even though everything runs fine in older Python environment. In this particular case, the error actually means that in a certain column there are two unique values (e.g. `a` and `b`) but related pandas functions generate indices `[0, 1, 2]`. This implies that index `2` is without its own unique value. Thus the error message.

Since the error did not seem to follow any obvious pattern, I "dived" into pandas code. I was able to track down the source of the problem into function `decons_group_index()` in *sorting.py* file. The issue could be illustrated on following piece of code.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([2076999867579399,
              2077965839147919,
              2078931810716439,
              2079897782284959,
              2080863753853479,
              2081829725421999,
              2082795696990519,
              2083761668559039])

y = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0])
factor = 160995261420
shape = 1

labels = (x - y) % (factor * shape) // factor

print(labels)
```

If I run the code in python `3.7.3.final.0`, I get `[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]`, which is expected behavior. However, if I run it in python `3.9.6.final.0`, I get `[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]`, which triggers the above mentioned type of error.

I wonder if you have experienced anything similar and if there is any simple and elegant way how to fix the issue. I am also not sure if this could be considered as a bug and thus should be reported somewhere.

Many thx in advance,

Macky

Comment: can you provide a problematic pandas example?

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is confidential - I would have to randomize it and ask for an approval. The whole issue could be really simplified to this example (I spent quite some time to isolate the issue). BTW, `labels = (x - y) % (factor * shape) // factor` is directly taken from function `decons_group_index()`. In other words, if python 3.9 produces the same result as python 3.7, the issue would be solved. I have also observed that splitting the aggregated dataframe into two parts or dropping some columns often help to solve the issue. So, I wonder if there is some overflow involved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - so it turned out to be a bug in numpy. Reported [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20025#issuecomment-933616603).

Macky